# How to use / find a Latex compiler in python

Tags: python, math, latex, pdflatex, latexmk

I am trying to run the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Tabular, Math, TikZ, Axis, \
    Plot, Figure, Matrix, Alignat
from pylatex.utils import italic
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'kitten.jpg')

    geometry_options = {"tmargin": "1cm", "lmargin": "10cm"}
    doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)

    with doc.create(Section('The simple stuff')):
        doc.append('Some regular text and some')
        doc.append(italic('italic text. '))
        doc.append('\nAlso some crazy characters: $&#{}')
        with doc.create(Subsection('Math that is incorrect')):
            doc.append(Math(data=['2*3', '=', 9]))

        with doc.create(Subsection('Table of something')):
            with doc.create(Tabular('rc|cl')) as table:
                table.add_hline()
                table.add_row((1, 2, 3, 4))
                table.add_hline(1, 2)
                table.add_empty_row()
                table.add_row((4, 5, 6, 7))

    a = np.array([[100, 10, 20]]).T
    M = np.matrix([[2, 3, 4],
                   [0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 2]])

    with doc.create(Section('The fancy stuff')):
        with doc.create(Subsection('Correct matrix equations')):
            doc.append(Math(data=[Matrix(M), Matrix(a), '=', Matrix(M * a)]))

        with doc.create(Subsection('Alignat math environment')):
            with doc.create(Alignat(numbering=False, escape=False)) as agn:
                agn.append(r'\frac{a}{b} &= 0 \\')
                agn.extend([Matrix(M), Matrix(a), '&=', Matrix(M * a)])

        with doc.create(Subsection('Beautiful graphs')):
            with doc.create(TikZ()):
                plot_options = 'height=4cm, width=6cm, grid=major'
                with doc.create(Axis(options=plot_options)) as plot:
                    plot.append(Plot(name='model', func='-x^5 - 242'))

                    coordinates = [
                        (-4.77778, 2027.60977),
                        (-3.55556, 347.84069),
                        (-2.33333, 22.58953),
                        (-1.11111, -493.50066),
                        (0.11111, 46.66082),
                        (1.33333, -205.56286),
                        (2.55556, -341.40638),
                        (3.77778, -1169.24780),
                        (5.00000, -3269.56775),
                    ]

                    plot.append(Plot(name='estimate', coordinates=coordinates))

        with doc.create(Subsection('Cute kitten pictures')):
            with doc.create(Figure(position='h!')) as kitten_pic:
                kitten_pic.add_image(image_filename, width='120px')
                kitten_pic.add_caption('Look it\'s on its back')

    doc.generate_pdf('full', clean_tex=False)
```

But I keep getting the following error:

pylatex.errors.CompilerError: No LaTex compiler was found
Either specify a LaTex compiler or make sure you have latexmk or pdfLaTex installed.

I can't seem to find out how to find a LaTex compiler. I have pdfLaTex installed but it doesnt seem to make a different. Any help is extremely appreciated.

Comment: on Linux you could try to use in console `which latex` to find full path to command `latex`. Or you could use command `find`.

Comment: https://github.com/JelteF/PyLaTeX/blob/v1.4.1/pylatex/document.py#L297 might be the place where that exception is raised. You can inspect the code leading to that to see what it tries to do in order to find a LaTeX compiler. You may be able to reproduce the issue that way, or add debug statements to that code to learn more like e.g. the call stack leading there.